# Delphi framework for IS units and conversions

Tags: delphi

We need a generic framework that will allow our application to do all kinds of conversions between the base units of the [International System of Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) and the derived units. It should i.e. be possible to add values with unit "meter" to values with unit "kilometer", and it should be able to determine what the unit of an expression is.

So if we calculate the product of a speed (m/s) and a time (h:mm:ss) then it should be able to determine that the resulting unit is distance (m).

Does anybody know if such a library is available somewhere, commercially or open source?

Comment: I tried Google for some terms that came up, but couldn't find any.
Should you want to roll your own this could be a starting point (not in Delphi):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23087/Measurement-Unit-Conversion-Library

Comment: Roll your own data type. Use a record with operator overloading. The record needs to contain the value as well as the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it directly that I've seen.

You have to convert one type into the other (or both into a common type), perform your operation, and then convert the results back.

Delphi (since 2007, at least) comes with the `ConvUnit` unit that has classes that will do this type thing, and there's a sample app that demonstrates called `ConvertIt`. YOu can do your own custom conversion types, which makes it pretty flexible.

There's more info in the [Delphi documentation wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/ConvertIt_Sample).

[image: ConvertIt sample screen image]

Comment: This is not sufficient. You need a data type that encapsulates the dimensions as well as the value

Comment: Your reaction to my comment is inexplicable. The missing ingredient in your answer is handling of dimensions. I just pointed that out. You can either take the hint, or not.

Comment: Quite a useful thing on its own, and definitely whatever you build should start on this as a base. +1.